# Как ловить события кликов по элементам форм LiveTex с помощью jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день! Клиент попросил для формы livetex на сайте реализовать отправку данных в Цели Яндекс-метрики при клике по некоторым её элементам. Форма подключается JS-скриптоблоком в тело главной страницы, т.е. HTML генерится с помощью JS и ихнего сервера. У LiveTex поддержка целей Яндекса пока что в разработке, поэтому надо самим что-то изобретать. Я узнал div class этих элементов через "Инспектировать элемент" в Мозилле и написал в теле основной страницы сайта скрипты с jQuery, которые ловят клики по этим классам - и далее вызывают yaCounterMMMM.reachGoal('xwidget2');

Однако ничего не происходит - jQuery вообще не ловит события, которые генерируются при клике по компонентам livetex'овой формы, несмотря на то что после окончания загрузки страницы это вроде бы такой же полноправный HTML, как и свой родной. Он же инспектируются в Мозилле!

Можно ли что-то сделать? Техподдержка LT молчит.

Вот тестовая страница, на которой надо отладить сам алгоритм и потом перенести на главную (пока что для упрощения вместо reachGoal() поставили вызов банального алерта):
http://samurai.spb.ru/testm.html

Там справа будет всплывать телефонная трубка (не снизу - нижнюю форму трогать не надо), надо щелкнуть по ней, развернется однострочная форма (с зеленой телефонной трубкой и зеленой кнопкой отправки) к которой надо наш обработчик прикрутить. (Прикол - трубка всплывает лишь с 10 утра до 20 вечера, на ночь Livetex'овские её отключают).

PS. Обработчик типовой:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.lt-xbutton-icons').click(function(){
        alert('Клик по LiveTex элементу!');
        return true;
}); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял этот самый LiveTex генерирует свой DOM. `$(document).ready` же срабатывает на завершение начального DOM. Т.е. в момент когда вы пытаетесь получить `$('.lt-xbutton-icons')` их ещё не будет существовать. Проверьте это через

```
console.log("element exist: " + !($('.lt-xbutton-icons').length === 0))
```

Если это так, то корректным решением будет повесится на некий `on-DOM-ready` колбэк LiveTex, а если его нет, то на общий [on-DOM-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom). Либо захачить через `setInterval` - ждать пока не появятся нужные элементы.

[В комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445752/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-livetex-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery#comment471924_445760) ещё предложили использовать [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) из jQuery: `$(..).click(fn)` является синонимом `$(".lt-xbutton-icons").on("click", fn)`, а вариант с delegated events выглядит так: `$(document).on("click", ".lt-xbutton-icons", fn)`. Т.е. селектор переезжает из $() в параметр on() и проверяется не в момент регистрации обработчика, а в момент собственно клика.

Последний вариант мне кажется самым элегантным, в силу точного попадания в суть проблемы. Единственное не знаю насколько у него велики накладные расходы.

Comment: Если дело именно в этом, то можно еще использовать [delegated events из jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events): `$(..).click(fn)` является синонимом `$(".lt-xbutton-icons").on("click", fn)`, а вариант с delegated events выглядит как-то так: `$(document).on("click", ".lt-xbutton-icons", fn)`. Т.е. селектор переезжает из `$()` в параметр `on()` и проверяется не в момент регистрации обработчика, а в момент собственно клика.

Comment: @Nickolay да, похоже так тоже можно. Скорее всего это даже лучший вариант. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: "Т.е. в момент когда вы пытаетесь поверить событие $('.lt-xbutton-icons') ещё не будет существовать"


=стоп, а ведь проверка в обработчике осуществляется уже после того, как я кликнул, ибо использую я $('.class').click(). А кликаю я именно после того, как элемент был полностью сформирован. Момент регистрации по идее не должен играть никакой роли.

Comment: @NDanilov2015 кликаете после, а обработчик навешиваете до, не?

Comment: Обработчик писал штатным образом, которым он на обычных HTML-страницах работает, т.е.  $(document).ready(function()

PS. С делегированными событиями заработало, большое спасибо!

Comment: @NDanilov2015 ну я и пишу же вам, что у вас DOM не в html, а строится *после* загрузки страницы, т.е. после `$(document).ready`. Поэтому и не работает "обычным" способом.